# UV Tiling & Offset input values from World Position - incorrect behavior?

Tags: unity, unity-shader-graph

I'm using ShaderGraph in 2020.1.0f1. I have some shader experience, but it's all been handwriting shaders. I have experience with node-based things of this nature by way of Substance Designer. I'm working on a shader that should allow for seamless visibility between quads by changing the UV offset of a noise pattern based on the world position of the quad.

That said, I'm running into two things. This short (0:05) video shows how I'm expecting this to work - as the X/Y values of the UV Offset are changed, the continuous flow of the noise is smooth.

https://youtu.be/YAd9BtAWVRM

So, I add a position node and a split node, feed the world position into the split, and feed R/G from the split to X/Y of the Vector2 node. That does two things: it makes the preview boxes 3D (becomes a sphere instead of a quad), and "expands" the apparent tiling:

[image]

I'm guessing this is because the value from the split is a Vector1 rather than a float, though it seems odd that there's no implicit conversion, or that Vector1 values applied to UV Offset would change the actual appearance.

So, is this due to it being a Vector1 rather than a float? If so, is there a node that can convert from Vector1 to float? Am I going about this the wrong way entirely?

Comment: I don't think there's a meaningful difference between float and Vector1 here. Note that in your video example, the only thing affecting the tiling is the UV input. The offset is constant for all points. In your example with the split, now you have two competing factors shifting the noise lookup: the UV coordinate, and the world position. Both of these are changing simultaneously, and depending on whether they're changing in the same direction or opposite, you'll run through your noise space faster or slower, compressing or expanding the tiling.

Comment: @DMGregory - I agree that Vector1/float is pretty much the same thing (and the ShaderGraph doesn't have a float option anyway). The world position and UV coords will be static for any given object, but two quads next to each other should seamlessly blend together (appear as one longer object), which is my intent.  In the video, I was mostly showing that for any value of x or y, it was simply shifting the noise (which makes sense given it's an offset value).  When plugging in r/g from the world position, it's changing much more than just the offset.  Maybe it's a bug?

Comment: Sounds like you want the world position of the object center, not the world position of the pixel being shaded. If so, you're using the wrong node for that.

Comment: Interesting...  what would be the correct node? Even so, I could see that making things not line up, but it's weird that it would change the scale the way it does.

Comment: It's actually almost inevitable that it would change the scale this way, as I explained in my first comment. If you just want seamless matching based on world position, have you considered taking UV out of the equation entirely and plugging your Vector2 combiner node directly into your noise input?

Comment: Well, that is easier now, isn't it.  Thanks - that did what I needed it to do.

Comment: If you've solved your problem, want to post your solution as an Answer below?